# writing Map<String, List<Map<String,Object>>> data into excel using apache poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am working on creating excel file using Map<String, List<Map<String,Object>>> data in springboot application using apache poi library.

I have data: {Sheet1=[{header1=abc, header2=def, header3=ghi}], Sheet2=[{header1=ab, header2=de, header3=gh}], Sheet3=[{header1=bc, header2=ef, header3=hi}]}

I need to create excel as below.

```
  **data.xlsx**

 | header1 header2 header3 |   |header1 header2 header3 |  |header1 header2 header3 |
    abc     def     ghi          ab      de      gh          bc      ef      hi
  <Sheet1>                      <Sheet2>                    <Sheet3>
```

I am able to create different sheets with name of key from Map<String, List<Map<String,Object>>> data.I am trying to create excel sheets from value i.e List<Map<String,Object>, where the String should be used as header and Object data as respective rows of header. I am trying to populate the row of excel sheet with header names. the for loop runs and populates only last cell value.

I wrote the below code to populate header names as below.

```
//code to create excel sheet

Map<String, List<Map<String, Object>>> data = info.getData(); //getting data from database

 XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:...path"+"data.xlsx"));

  Set<String> keyset = data.keySet();
  for(String key: keyset){

    XSSFSheet sheet = wb.crateSheet(key);
    int rowNo = 0;
    List<Map<String, Object>> list = data.get(key);

    for(Map<String, Object> value : list){

      XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(rowNo++);

      Set<String> headerKeyset = value.keySet();

      for(String keyHeader : headerKeyset){

       int cellnum= 0;
       XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);
       cell.setCellValue(keyHeader);
}}}
 wb.write(out);
 out.close();

.
.
.
```

I'm able to create different Sheets/tab in Excel file with names Sheet1,Sheet2,Sheet3.
But unable to fill in proper header and data, only last cell value is being populated as below when I run above code.

```
  **data.xlsx**

 | header3                  |   |header3                 |  |header3                |
    
  <Sheet1>                      <Sheet2>                    <Sheet3>
```

Can someone please let me know what I have to change to make it working?

Comment: can try moving **wb.write(out)** inside the loop, the reason is as you are out of loop only the last iterated value is written to spread sheet.. can try making the change?

Comment: @zakir Hussain I tried moving WB.write(out) inside loop. But now no additional sheets are created in work book and only first value is displayed as header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code snippet is not compilable. So I expect you modified it before post.
This line -> `for(Map<String, Object> value : list({`

In regards of code probably you missed or missplaced curly braces. In this particular example your line `wb.write(out);` is called 3 times

Update: after your changes in code I see that you do not even use object value to fill data, only header. Use something like this:

```
XSSFRow hrow = sheet.createRow(0);
XSSFRow vrow = sheet.createRow(1);
for(Map<String, Object> value : list) {
    
    Set<String> headerKeyset = value.keySet();
    for(String keyHeader : headerKeyset) {
       int cellnum= 0;
       XSSFCell hcell = hrow.createCell(cellnum++);
       hcell.setCellValue(keyHeader);
       XSSFCell vcell = vrow.createCell(cellnum++);
       vcell.setCellValue(value.getValue(keyHeader));
    }
}
```